# using the print command in special situations Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to use a `print` afterwards `if not`commandos and if so, how?

```
def Move(self, tile, startx, starty): 
    if self.board[xstart][ystart] != ' ' or not self.isOnBoard(xstart, ystart):
        print('The coordinates is not on the board')
        return False
```

Comment: Please add an example with sample input and requested output...

Comment: Is that exactly how your code looks? If it is, you need to indent your `print` and `break` statement.

Comment: I thought my example as shown above was enough, which include a requested output "not valid" if the coordinates x and y is not on the board @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @PythonGirl It's easy: Edit your post and paste all your code and the error traceback.

Comment: @Avión Please don't say stuff like that! We generally **don't** want people to paste all their code: we want to see a [mcve].

Comment: There is no error traceback, the only problem which I've noticed that `if not` commandos does not read the `print` afterwards

Comment: @PythonGirl can be that because `onBoard(x,y)` returns true? Try chaning to condition to `if onBoard(x,y):` and see what happens.

Comment: That means the `if not onBoard(x, y)` is never True. So there's probably something wrong with your `onBoard` function.

Comment: ohhhhh, no I mean I want the `print` when the function returns wrong! So that is then `if on Board`

Comment: Nope didn't work

Comment: `if not onBoard(x, y): print('Not Valid')` will print if `onBoard(x, y)` returns a False-ish value. So you should try to make a MCVE: a cut-down version of your program that we can run, which has this same problem. Post it here and we'll help you debug it.

Comment: Be sure to include the `onBoard` function, if it's short enough.

Comment: I have updated! with a move valid example

Comment: The problem is that **still** when I input a coordinat that is outside of the gameboard, it only gives me Errors when I want the function to break and print that that move is not valid

Comment: You deleted your post, so I'll post this here. I modified one of your functions, and the original board *is* being modified when the copy is changed: https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/5bfa5afbd21c5b65d3bd6284df0f1eb8

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that still when I input a coordinat that is outside of the gameboard, it only gives me Errors when I want the function to break and print that that move is not valid  -- PythonGirl

Given this. It would seem you want to test the validity of whether startx, starty are even present on the board ( a predefined board I assume ). In that case wouldn't rearranging the tests fix it. As you are first testing if the values exist ( via self.board[xstart][ystart] ) without actually testing if they are on the board with your isOnBoard function

```
def Move(self, tile, startx, starty):
if not self.isOnBoard(xstart, ystart) or self.board[xstart][ystart] == ' ':
    print('The coordinates is not on the board')
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is happening inside the onBoard function; perhaps something similar.

But when you check

```
   if self.board[xstart][ystart] != ' '
```

with xstart and/or ystart outside of the valid range (which I am assuming is what you mean by "not on the board", you will get an error because you are trying to access something which doesn't exist.

You need to check that the values of xstart and ystart are within the valid range *before* using them.

If that is what you are doing in isOnBoard, you should check that first, and then check the contents of that spot on the board.

If you give the code for isOnBoard, we might be able to help you with it, if it is not working properly.